# Have I found the equation for this circuit and simplified it correctly?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

Lets say that the 5k, 40k and 20k are R1, R2 and R3 respectively.
I've created an equation that allows you to find Vo using the rules of ideal op-amps using R1, R2 and Vs. Is it correct?

$$V_o = \frac{R_2 V_s}{R_1} + V_s$$

[image]

So, in the case of \$V_s=2\text{ V}\$ then \$V_o = 18\text{ V}\$?

Comment: Keep in mind that if the opamp output needs to get to +18V then its positive power rail has to be higher than that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's correct, the equation and the example numbers.

You could also write it as $$\frac {v_o}{v_s} = 1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}$$

Answer (score 2):

It's correct.

Remember that V(+) = V(-) implies that the output is defined regardless of the value of \$R_3\$. This, in turn, implies that this ideal op-amp can provide infinite current. You could exchange the \$20k\Omega\$ for a \$0.1\Omega\$ and you'll get the same result.

Obviously, real-world op-amps have a finite output current drive, so you have to check datasheets in order to make sure that the op-amp golden rules are a good approximation.